# Relation between group of components and a torsion subgroup in a long exact sequence in cohomology

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, k-theory

Consider the short exact sequence (call it "coefficient sequence'')

$$ 0 \to {\bf{Z}} \to {\bf{R}} \to U(1) \to 0$$

Suppose $X$ is a topological space. The long-exact sequence in cohomology derived from the coefficient sequence above reads

$$ \cdots \to H^{p-1}(X; {\bf{Z}}) \to H^{p-1}(X; {\bf{R}}) \to H^{p-1}(X; U(1)) \to H^{p}(X; {\bf{Z}}) \to \cdots $$

By "the group of components $\overline{H}^{p-2}(X; U(1))$'' one presumably means the [quotient group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_component#Component_group)

$$ \overline{H}^{p-2}(X; U(1)) = H^{p-2}(X; U(1))/H^{p-2}(X; U(1))_{0}$$

where $H^{p-2}(X; U(1))_{0}$ denotes the identity component of $H^{p-2}(X; U(1))$.

How does one argue that $\overline{H}^{p-2}(X; U(1)) = H^{p-1}(X; {\bf{Z}})_{\text{tors}}$, the torsion subgroup of $H^{p-1}(X; {\bf{Z}})$?

[This question stems from the discussion around (2.18) of a paper by [Moore and Witten [hep-th/9912279]](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9912279).]

If $\beta$ is the map

$$\beta: H^{p-2}(X, {\bf{R}}) \longrightarrow H^{p-2}(X, U(1))$$

I am able to argue that $$H^{p-1}(X,Z)_{\text{tors}} \cong H^{p-2}(X, U(1))/\text{im}(\beta)$$

I guess my question is: how does one show that $\text{im}(\beta)$ is the connected component of the identity, i.e. $H^{p-2}(X, U(1))_{0}$?

Comment: What is the topology on these cohomology groups? If you have the definition one should be able to show that $H^*(X,\mathbb{R})$ is connected and $\beta$ is continuous.

Comment: I would hope that 
is a continuous map, and so, it maps a connected set into a connected set. So the image of  is connected. Further,  is a group homomorphism so the identity maps onto the identity. However, I agree that one needs to be sharper about the topology on the cohomology groups. All one can say is that  is a compact, smooth, oriented Riemannian manifold. So the cohomology groups are finitely generated. (Typo in my previous [now deleted] comment: infinitely --> finitely.)